# Trying to grep non-matching patterns saved in a variable which is read from a file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

The script I'm writing is trying to grep out non-matching patterns in which the patterns are provided to the grep function as a bash variable. The variable right now consists of just one pattern which is 'tmp$' to grep out records ending with tmp.
Here is the code for it

```
 cat file | grep -v -F "${EXCLUSIONS}"
```

where EXCLUSIONS is the variable

```
 cat file:
 /bin/xyz
 /bin/abc
 /tmp/dir/abc
 /helloworld/tmp

 echo $EXCLUSIONS:
 tmp$
 /bin

#Here I want the output to be only /tmp/dir/abc as one pattern\
#to exclude is anything that ends with tmp or /bin
```

The output still contains entries ending with tmp and what I assume the reason for this is that it doesn't consider the **$** at the end of the **tmp$** as a regex pattern. Is there a way in bash to achieve this working where I can use a variable like EXCLUSION which can contain both normal patterns and patterns with meta characters like $ or ^ to work as regular expressions?

Comment: Do you know what the `-F` option of grep does?

Comment: The `-F` option on grep means use _fixed_ strings ... not _regex_ — so the `$` does not mean end-of-line, it means a literal dollar-sign.  Try your same thing leaving out the `-F` and tell us what happens _then_ — `cat file | grep -v "${EXCLUSIONS}"`

Comment: Also, `grep` operates on files, so you don't need to `cat` the file, you can just `grep -v "${EXCLUSIONS}" file`

Comment: @StephenP  Will it work for all my patterns which are delimited by newline in my EXCLUSIONS variable if I don't use the -F option.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to show us concise, testable sample input and expected output then we'd be able to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the word `pattern` in the context of searching for text in files as it's ambiguous - always use `string` or `regexp`, whichever it is you mean. To search for a string in a file is:

```
grep -F 'string' file
```

and to search for a (BRE) regexp is:

```
grep 'regexp' file
```

Since you want the `$` at the end of `tmp$` to be treated as the `end-of-string` regexp metacharacter you must want to match on a regexp so then you'd use:

```
grep -v "$EXCLUSIONS" file
```

btw by convention and to avoid clashing with other variable names already exported and present in your environment, don't use all upper case variable names unless your variable is exported.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't grep out regexp and strings using one single grep? I'm not clear on this so just want to confirm that!

Comment: Yes, that s what it means. You can "grep" for regexps and strings using one single call to awk, though, if that's what you want.

Comment: Can you give me details of how it can be done together using awk?

Comment: `awk '/foo/ && index($0,"bar")' file` would look for a regexp `foo` and a string `bar` - it's equivalent to `gep -E 'foo' file | grep -F 'bar'`

Answer (score -1):

I think you shouldn't use -F, this means "Fixed string" and not supporting Regex.
and EXCLUSIONS shouldn't ends with $. You should use $ for specifying end of line in grep.
Look at this example.

```
cat test.txt
row1
row2
row3
1tmp
2tmp
tmp1
tmp2


echo $EXCLUSIONS
tmp

cat test.txt | grep -v ${EXCLUSIONS}$
row1
row2
row3
tmp1
tmp2
```

I hope it's be useful.

Comment: Google UUOC and quoting shell variables.